# What does cmd /C mean?

Tags: command-line, cmd

I can understand `cmd` but not `cmd /c`. I was trying to invoke a java program from the current for which I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C java helloworld");` There arises my doubt.

Comment: To Moderators, is there a provision to move this to appropriate portal/subsidiary of stack overflow. That way this item will not be closed and users will be able to contribute more? I guess this should go to something similar to super user?

Comment: I find it a perfectly valid question for SO.

Comment: Start CMD in a directory: ***`CMD /k cd /D C:\\`***   (where C:\ is the desired path)

Answer (score 338):

The part you should be interested in is the `/?` part, which should solve most other questions you have with the tool.

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\>cmd /?
Starts a new instance of the Windows XP command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
/Q      Turns echo off
/D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see below)
/A      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be ANSI
/U      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be
        Unicode
/T:fg   Sets the foreground/background colors (see COLOR /? for more info)
/E:ON   Enable command extensions (see below)
/E:OFF  Disable command extensions (see below)
/F:ON   Enable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/F:OFF  Disable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
        delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
        variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
        at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
        loop.
/V:OFF  Disable delayed environment expansion.
```

Comment: there's also a command to "pause" the cmd window after output: "cmd /c  file_name & PAUSE" it is bit different from cmd /k

Comment: what if a given command is kind of a server that starts it's own loop? should we use /C or /K?

Comment: While executing command in C# via 'Process' is using /C mandatory in Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 operating system?

Comment: I came here becasue its not behaving as described. Im runnig from git bash and cmd /c "dir" or any command will just leave me in cmd prompt without executing the ocmmand.

Comment: cmd /? | more ...to page the command switches

Comment: To start CMD in a specific path, use: ***`CMD /k cd /D C:\\`***   (where C:\ is the desired path)

Answer (score 136):

`/C` Carries out the command specified by the string and then terminates.

You can get all the cmd command line switches by typing `cmd /?`.

Comment: But why would one want to?  Why not just call the command directly, like "java helloworld"

Comment: because you might not be in CMD but you just wan to use cmd to execute a command for you. eg I am running a bash script and want it to execute a command that cmd can do but bash can not.

Answer (score 30):

```
CMD.exe

Start a new CMD shell

Syntax
      CMD [charset] [options] [My_Command] 

Options       

**/C     Carries out My_Command and then
terminates**
```

From the help.