# Which C++ unit test framework should I use to run tests that involve libcurl?

Tags: c++, cmake, libcurl, googletest, googlemock

I have written code that uses libcURL to retrieve information from a given webpage. I want to write a unit test for this code. I have attempted to do this using cmake but I have run into a variety of problems. Is there another framework that will allow me to accomplish this more easily?

Below is detailed information about the issues I have been having with cmake:

Previously I was sending a test webpage to a local host using tinyweb as part of the unit test. I then used multiple commands to input values to my code (which would retrieve the relevant information from the local host)and kill tinyweb. The overall structure is similar to this:

[CTest with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065220/ctest-with-multiple-commands)

I have run into a number of issues. Once the command to start tiny.exe is executed the next line of the ctest will not run until tiny.exe has been killed.

I previously tried to do something similar using batch files but tiny.exe was being killed at unsuspected times.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would recommend gtest and gmock. Firstly, unless you control the website, you can't guarantee that the content that you request will even exist. Secondly, even if the web-site does exist, you can't guarantee that the content will remain constant.

So 1) 
Set up your own site on local host. You can use gtest for that. 2) Then you can use gmock to simulate what you expect today's content of your website will be.

3) You can also use google mock to simulate DNS failures, connection problems, etc. But for now, start simple.

Comment: I have been doing some research on this and gtest does not appear to have any inbuilt functionality that would set up a local host.

Can you clarify what you meant by this? Should I just set up the local host in setUp()?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. By "use gtest for that", I meant you could use gtest to test against a web server on localhost, not that it would be one. As far as setting up a webserver, if you have a printer on your network, it probably has one. Just connect to it via its IP address. You can test that first in a browser to see what to expect.

Or research setting up a webserver to find what would be easiest for you. There are a number of python minimal effort servers, for example.