# How should I receive output from Console application in WinForms on .Net Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console-application

I have a console application which I run through a WinForms application, which waits for the application to finish. How can I retrieve the output of the console application in my GUI, and what is the best way to wait for the console application to finish?

Comment: Any help in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Comment: Are they both .NET assemblies? If so, it would likely be easier for one application to call public methods of the other application than to implement interprocess communication.

Comment: Reworded assuming the console app is no-source-available.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with "Process" class.  Please refer to the ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property example available in the below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [Inter-Process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Since you're using .Net.  See [WCF Named-Pipes](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) for example.