# How to execute command on cmd from C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I want to run commands on the cmd from my C# app.

I tried:

```
string strCmdText = "ipconfig";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

**result:**

the cmd window pop but the command didn't do nothing.

why?

Comment: ipconfig is just a exe try `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start('ipconfig');`

Comment: ipconfig here could represent any complex command built using a string builder or other mechanism where hard coding was not a possibility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C ipconfig");
```

If you want to have cmd still opened use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K ipconfig");
```

Comment: and then how to send future commands?

Comment: It is very common for people to prepend a command invocation with `cmd /c` even though it's not always necessary.  In this case, since `ipconfig` is its own application (`ipconfig.exe`) and not a command built into `cmd.exe`, your first code snippet could be simplified to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ipconfig");`.

Answer (score 9):

from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C)

```
 public void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
    {
         try
         {
             // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
             // and "/c " as the parameters.
             // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
             // and then exit.
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

        // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
        // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        // Do not create the black window.
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        // Get the output into a string
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the command output.
        Console.WriteLine(result);
          }
          catch (Exception objException)
          {
          // Log the exception
          }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know it it's needed, but in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753402/1033581) they added `proc.WaitForExit();`.