# How to insert/run a Windows command (ping, getmac, vmic, etc) from VB .net - Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm new here and more than beginner in coding. I want, as an "on the side" project, create a tool coded in VB for the helpdesk team. I would like to type the computer ID in a text field and have several buttons below that performs windows command like ping, getmac, wmic, etc etc..

How is it possible to load or to integrate a windows prompt or even to as VB to call the dll to perform those windows commands. Is there a built-in tool in Visual Studio 12 that does that? I thought that it was the "Console" argument that could do this but I'm just way too n00b in coding to have it working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating forms read this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd492132.aspx

For executing processes use `Process.Start`.

If you need to read process output, see  [Process.start: how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

A good tutorial to start with : http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start-vbnet

Comment: Hi Bogdan. if I wish to start/load a command prompt in backgound, not to fully load the cmd UI, is there another command? Process.start mostly sounds like when I hit a button in my project, that it's gonna open the whole application instead of returning the information I need.

Comment: If you need to read process output, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output