# How to include a batch file command?

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have the following code which call and execute a batch file,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\tS\comm.bat";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Start();
string strGetInfo = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
strCMDOut = strGetInfo.Substring(strGetInfo.Length - 5, 3);
//MessageBox.Show(cmdOut);
proc.WaitForExit();
```

The `comm.bat` file contains the following,

```
@ECHO ON
java com.test.this send
```

Instead of calling a file to execute the bat file, how can I incorporate it within my C# code and prevent any file issue? (I need the output to be saved to a string as it is already doing it in the above code.)

Also, how do I do it silently, so the user doesn't see the CMD window and the operation takes place in the background?

I replaced the code with this:

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "java com.test.this send",
        RedirectStandardError = false,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
proc.Start();
string strGetInfo = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
strCMDOut = strGetInfo.Substring(strGetInfo.Length - 5, 3);
MessageBox.Show(strCMDOut);
```

I get a `.` in the message box instead of the code that the original code was displaying.

Comment: Calling a java program from a batch file from a process started in a C# program ... I doubt this is the correct approach for the problem.

Comment: What does `com.test.this` actually do?  Could you duplicate it's function in C#?

Comment: It has been working so far, just didn't want to call the batch file and embed it in my C# application instead.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Unfortunately it is a vendor application and not compatible with any C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About,
*how do I do it silently, so the user doesn't see the CMD window and the operation takes place in the background?*

You can suppress new window by setting this property of ProcessStartInfo.

```
CreateNoWindow = true
```

Answer (score 2):

It *may* be enough to:

```
var pro = Process.Start("java", "com.test.this send");
```

Considering that you have `@ECHO ON`, I presume you want to read an output of the process (in case it redirected from the inside of it).

For this read : [Process.start: how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

If this is not what you are asking for, please clarify.

Comment: With my code I am already doing it. I can read the output and save it to a string to be used at a later time within the application. I just want to eliminate the reading the bat file and have it embedded within my C# code.

Comment: @SiKni8: so try to invoce it like in linked example.

Comment: That seems like what I am looking to do, how can I add multiple arguements?

Comment: @SiKni8: according to the documentation, it's a single string so just pass them in a single string, like from example.

Comment: I updated my question with what I have and I get a `.` as a messagebox.

Comment: You may want to redirect and capture StdError also