# Reading output from console through asp.net

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, c

I am using this code to pass two numbers as input to an .exe of a C program file through asp.net and after that trying to read the output from console. I am having problem to read any output from the console.
My asp.net code is.

```
string returnvalue;

Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.FileName = ("C:\\Users\\...\\noname01.exe");
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.Start();
Thread.Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait("1");
Thread.Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait("~");
Thread.Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait("2");
Thread.Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait("~");
Thread.Sleep(500);

StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;

returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();

System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\...\\StudentOutput.txt");
file.WriteLine(returnvalue);
```

My C code to which am passing inputs is.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
    int a, b, c;

    printf("Enter two numbers to add\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

    c = a + b;

    printf("Sum of entered numbers = %d\n",c);

    return 0;
    }
```

I am having problem to read any output from the console.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Comment: i have tried it before and its not working

Answer (score 0):

use `StandardInput`, rather than in the `SendKeys`.

```
StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;

sw.WriteLine("1");
sw.WriteLine("2");
sw.Close();
```

...

```
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(".\\out.txt");//Simplified
file.WriteLine(returnvalue);
file.Close();
```