# How to redirect command line output to a ASPX page using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following is my code to run a command from aspx page using c#:

```
 string strcmd = "/k" + @"cd: C:\GWATS\bin\&&" + "waft_exe";
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", strcmd); 
 Response.Redirect("./result.aspx");
```

This is working fine. But I want to get the output from the cmd to my aspx page. Can anyone give me coding for this?
I am working on ASP.NET just for the past 1 week, hence I dont have any idea of this. So please give me a working code for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Answer (score 2):

You can get and read the Output from your command as:

```
var cCommandEx = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", strcmd);

string cRetStandardOut = cCommandEx.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

// before the redirect wait to exit and close it
cCommandEx.WaitForExit();
cCommandEx.Close();
```

and use it for your redirect.

You must also have set `RedirectStandardOutput = true,` on the `ProcessStartInfo()` of your process, if you do not read anything as it is.