# How to capture response returned by EXE file C#

Tags: c#

i want to pass param to another exe file which is also developed by c#.
i know how to pass parameter to exe file from my application. this way i can pass param to exe file

```
Process p= new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "demo.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "param1 param2";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

now demo.exe file will do some job and will return some data. i want to capture that data at my end. so guide what i alter in my code to capture response return by demo.exe file. help me with altered code. thanks

**probably below solution may solve my issue. i will test it.
When you create your Process object set StartInfo appropriately:**

```
var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "program.exe",
        Arguments = "command line arguments to your executable",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

then start the process and read from it:

proc.Start();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // do something with line
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Comment: Use `Process.ExitCode`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and store your result in a file:

```
using(Process proc = new Process())
{
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = <your exe>;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = <your parameters>;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += LogOutputHandler;
    proc.Start();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}

private static void LogOutputHandler(object proc, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    <write your result to a file here>
}
```

Comment: how to return value from the exe file which will be called from my application. suppose i am going to call demo.exe file. so what i need to write or how to return value from demo apps as a result my main apps can read that value. please guide me with code like how to return data. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is the old-fashioned process exit code.

You can use `p.ExitCode` to capture the result in your code  once the process has terminated.

Also, demo.exe needs to set `Environment.ExitCode` before exiting.

Typically, 0 is used to report success.

Comment: suppose demo.exe will return a string value which i want to capture from my application. just guide me what code i need to write?

Comment: Many different solutions can be used...
Easy : you can output result to a file and read it in the other project.
Less easy : you can do cross-process comunication with WCF as mentioned by @Beno

Answer (score 1):

You can check the ExitCode of the process if it just int.
otherwise you can use WCF pipeline to communicate between the process

Answer (score 0):

The return value for main is 'void' so you can't return any item.  You can use standard output which is a stream to pass back info.  An easy method is to return an XML stream back to the calling program which is easily parsed.