# Process.Start with error output into log in C#

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

Below is my command i execute over command line in Windows.

```
C:\>"C:\application.exe" "C:\filename.txt" 2>> "C:\errorlog.log"
```

This command below works without log file, but i would like to add the output into log file.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"""C:\application.exe"", @"""C:\filename.txt""");
```

I would like to do the same in C#, but it doesn't work for me, this is my code i have now:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"""C:\application.exe"", @"""C:\filename.txt"" 2>> ""C:\errorlog.log""");
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process.start: how to get the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

Comment: I didn´t understand the "2" before ">>"...  Why is it there?

Answer (score 0):

send parameters as string :

try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\application.exe" , @"C:\filename.txt 2>> C:\errorlog.log");
```

Comment: This is the same as the code that doesn't work, you've just removed the quotes around the filenames.