# How do I redirect cmd ftp ls command output to a C# variable

Tags: c#, cmd, ftp, ls

I have been trying to figure this for hours, and can't seem to find a straight answer. I have found similar questions but none seem to work with what I am trying to do here. I am trying to avoid having to write to a file. If I can redirect to a variable, that would be great.

Given the following code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {

        const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

        var cmd = new Process();

        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.Start();

        using (var stdin = cmd.StandardInput) {
            stdin.WriteLine("ftp");
            stdin.WriteLine("open localhost");
            stdin.WriteLine("anonymous");
            var hWnd = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
            stdin.WriteLine("ls");
            stdin.WriteLine("close localhost");
            stdin.WriteLine("bye");

        }
        cmd.WaitForExit();
        cmd.Close();
    }
```

How do I redirect the ls output to a variable?

Comment: [Process.start: how to get the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

Comment: Console.SetOut() method ?

Comment: Why are you running `ftp.exe` via `cmd.exe`? You are adding unnecessary complexity and another possible point of failure. Run it directly.

Comment: Yes. That's what I ended up doing. After I was done with the code it hit me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to grab output from the console by handling the OutputDataReceived event. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;
            const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

            var cmd = new Process();

            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            // Capture output
            cmd.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data) == false)
                {
                    var x = args.Data;
                }
            };

            cmd.Start();
            // Need to call this method in order to raise the OutputDataReceivedEvent for each line of output
            cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();


            using (var stdin = cmd.StandardInput)
            {
                stdin.WriteLine("ftp");
                stdin.WriteLine("open localhost");
                stdin.WriteLine("anonymous");
                var hWnd = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
                PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
                stdin.WriteLine("ls");
                stdin.WriteLine("close localhost");
                stdin.WriteLine("bye");
            }
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            cmd.Close();
        }

        private void PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wmKeydown, int vkReturn, int i)
        {
            // No idea what you are doing here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. I need to filter out first few lines and the last, but atleast I get the content. Thank you.