# Runing command into CMD and get output into variable using C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I need to run a command into CMD window and want to get result into a variable.
I used below code to do the same but the out put is incorrect

```
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = " wmic.exe /node:(computername or ip address) computersystem get username ",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        proc.Start();
        string line = "";
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            line += (line.Length > 0 ? "-----" : "") + proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        }

        proc.WaitForExit();
```

**Out put**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]-----Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.----------C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0>
```

But when i run this command into CMD window it shows the current logged in users name.

Can any one help me to solve the issue.

> Note :- The given command is used to get the current logged in users
>   name on network system by using it's IP Address.

Comment: do you have to use `cmd`? you could just use `wimc` directly. also, .net has apis for the logged in user name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect cmd ftp ls command output to a C# variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674991/how-do-i-redirect-cmd-ftp-ls-command-output-to-a-c-sharp-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the /c option for cmd

```
C:\>cmd /?
Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
```

I would question the need for cmd.exe here. You can just invoke wmic directly as below

```
var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "wmic.exe",
        Arguments = "/node:localhost computersystem get username ",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

proc.Start();
string line = "";
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    line += (line.Length > 0 ? "-----" : "") + proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}

proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you go to the trouble of invoking a commandline tool and parsing its results if [`System.Management`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management(v=vs.110).aspx) has all the classes you need to obtain the information in-process and managed?

```
var ip = "127.0.0.1";
var scope = new ManagementScope(
    String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", ip),
    new ConnectionOptions { Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate });
scope.Connect();

var users = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    scope,
    new ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_LoggedonUser"))
        .Get()
        .GetEnumerator();

while(users.MoveNext())
{
        var user =  users.Current["antecedent"];
        var mo = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(user.ToString()));

        try
        {
            var username = mo.Properties["name"];
            Console.WriteLine("username {0}", username.Value);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mo);
        }
}
```

All you have to do is create a [ManagementScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use the [ManagementObjectSearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to run any [WMI Query Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) statement by using one of the available [WMI Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn792258(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you have a working `wmic` call you can always add `/TRACE:ON` so you can inspect the calls being made. Use `wmic /?` to see the aliasses.

Comment: I've added System.Management Name space into my code and tried your code but it troughs error {the type or namespace name ManagementScope could not be found}.

Comment: Change in reference solve above issue but it troughs error {Not Found} at below line of code :-
var username = mo.Properties["name"];

Comment: @AshishRathore That is strange. On which Operating System are you and which version of the .Net framework? Are you running this for your local machine or are you connecting to a remote box. If so, what OS is that remote box running? What is in `user.ToString()`? does it contain a username with domain and the serverpath it is on?

Comment: user.ToString() = "\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain=\"IDR-ITD-SS169\",Name=\"IUSR\""

Local System OS = Windows7

Remote System OS = Windows7

Comment: @AshishRathore for some reason even an administrator while being elevated is not allowed to get to some properties on some managementobjects. I tried to find a way to prevent using a try/catch block but I didn't find another solution, so try/catch it is .. ;(