# opening up a browser using a console app, get some data and pass it back into the application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, console-application, google-oauth

I am trying to get the Google authorization code using a simple C# console application. The whole process is pretty simple: sending a request using a url containing a unique `Client Id` to Google Oauth2 endpoint, logging into the Google account and then get the authorization code:

```
string url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?whatever";
Process.Start("chrome.exe", url); // open up browser so user can log in
// get the auth code from chrome
```

How I can get that generated code from Google chrome and pass it back to my app?

Comment: did you find an answer for the above said problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start another process that opens a web server. This web server will simply return the request URL code param it's getting.

In the OAuth flow set the callback URL to `http://localhost:8080` (you will need to set it in the [console](https://console.developers.google.com/) as well).

So after the user consent, Google will redirect to localhost. 
your web server will catch the request (`localhost?code=auth_code`) and return the `auth_code` to the console like [described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output) here