# c# console-application - how to unite processes under windows

Tags: c#, windows, console-application, exe

I have few console-applications processes that I run under windows. Each process runs under separate window and it looks messy. Is there a way to unite the processes under one hub that will manage them?

Comment: What kind of work do these console applications do? If they're doing daemon-y (server) things, you might be better served using services instead. Any UI (if necessary) would then be separate from the actual work they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new console application that will launch others with special parameters (to hide windows) and receive their standart output, so it will be possible to show output from all processes in your window.

In some cases alternative way could be to convert those processes to Windows services.

Update: googled for quick example. It is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4665/WebControls/) or in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output) SO question