# multiple command one by one in cmd.exe via c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, windows, cmd

I trying to run the following command in cmd.exe by c# code.

1. mkdir myfolder
2. cd myfolder
3. git init
4. git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.company.com/testgroup/server.git
5. git fetch --dry-run
6. cd ..
7. rmdir myfolder

I don't know how to pass all the arguments in single `Process.Start();`. After run the 4th command I will take the output `string` and do some operation with that `string`.

I tried like this

```
        const string strCmdText = "/C mkdir myfolder& cd myfolder& git init & git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & git fetch --dry-run & cd .. & rmdir myfolder";
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Above command works properly. But I do not know how to get the execution text from `cmd.exe`. The text which I want is shown in below image.

[image: The text I want]

I used below code to get the output `string`. But at the line of reading the output(`string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`), the execution stopped. I means it will not go to next line also it will not terminate the program. Simply show the lack screen.

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C mkdir myfolder& cd myfolder& git init & git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & git fetch --dry-run & cd .. & rmdir myfolder";
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.Start();
        string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

How do I get the output `string`?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Comment: Yeah. But not used to clear my exception. My output string will be " ".

Comment: Could always just do the mkdir/rmdir/cd in C# via the IO namespace

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'ReadToEnd', you will wait for end of stream. You should use 'Read' or 'ReadLine' for reading parts of available stream context:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C mkdir myfolder& cd myfolder& git init & git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & git fetch --dry-run & cd .. & rmdir myfolder";
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmd.Start();

while (!cmd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    string line = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: I altered my code as you said but I facing the same black screen exception in `while (!cmd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)` line

Comment: Very strange, because for me it works fine. Try this on clear C# console project.