# using ffmpeg in Azure function to cut files using c#

Tags: c#, azure, ffmpeg, azure-functions

I have written an Azure function in C# which will cut a big mp4 files into some small duration. I have copied everything that is required (ffmpeg executeable, video file) in home directory via KUDU console. But when I run the the function it runs for more than 5 minutes and it doesn't give any files in the home directory.

Function :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("Executing");
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\home\ffmpeg.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-i D:\home\AmnestyInternational.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 D:\home\cut.mp4";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        log.Info(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        log.Info("Cutting starts:"+DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        log.Info("Cutting ends :"+DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        log.Info(output);
    }
}
```

Output seen on Azure function Console:

```
2017-03-24T11:06:00.705 Function started (Id=df082f54-719a-415f-b7f1-b10548a213be)
2017-03-24T11:06:00.721 Executing
2017-03-24T11:06:00.721 D:\Windows\system32
2017-03-24T11:06:00.721 Cutting start :11:06:00 AM
2017-03-24T11:07:14  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2017-03-24T11:08:14  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2017-03-24T11:09:14  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2017-03-24T11:10:14  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
2017-03-24T11:11:00.758 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.ManualTriggerCSharp1.
```

When I try to execute this same command on KUDU console or my own PC it only take 1.5 mins and I get a file of the desired duration

Could anyone please help me with this? What I might be missing?

Comment: maybe your computer is just faster than the cloudoption you booked?

Comment: Event when I am executing the above command in KUDU console it takes around 1.5 mins.

Comment: Did you check if you azure-vm has hardware acceleration for video transcoding?

Comment: No, I haven't. How do I check that?

Comment: I doubt it has, since you'd need an i7 or a mid/high end graphics card for it. but you can just check with the console which hardware you "have" an then check if it supports it.

Comment: When I manually try to execute the above command in azure-vm it runs fine and withing 1-2 mins. So I guess hardware is not an issue over here.

Comment: If running the same thing directly from Kudu console works, it's a bit puzzling as they both use the same sandbox and execution environment. Try using Kudu Process explorer while your function is running to make sure the process is still active.

Comment: Yes from the KUDU console I am using powershell, when I do 'get-process' I can see an entry for 'ffmpeg' process while my function is running.

Answer (score 2):

One improvement would be to get incremental progress updates from stdout, assuming that your process has output. I believe that `ReadToEnd()` will block until your process exits (and here it appears to timeout first). See some sync & async examples here: [Process.start: how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

The maximum timeout for consumption plan is 5 minutes, but if you run your function on a dedicated app service then you can set the timeout to any value of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why FFMPEG wasn't executing, until I realized I needed to be in the same folder as the EXE (in your case, `D:\home`).  This was the line of code I was missing:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"D:\home");
```

After that:

```
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\home";
process.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
```

etc.