# Process Get the outpout of a CMD command

Tags: c#, process

Im trying to get the outpout of my CMD command and i get the wrong outpout:

here's my cmd command : cm whoami

here's the outpout i should get (CMD outpout) :

```
C:\Users\Joevin>cm whoami
JoevinFerret
```

here's my code :

```
 Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "cm whoami",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            string outpout = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

here's the outpout that i get :
`outpout = "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.804]"`

Comment: Try `ReadToEnd()` instead of `ReadLine()`

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with your example (hints: `cmd.exe /c ...`, `ReadLine()` only captures first line of multi-line output, attempt to run your command manually and see what output it produces).  If you search SO ("[c#] cmd output") you'll find a multitude of related (or exact same) questions and answers. Just [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112187/c-sharp-get-cmd-output-just-as-shown-in-real-cmd-window).

Comment: Ok thanks i have change my ReadLine() to ReadToEnd() add a WaitForExit() to my process and add "/c" at the begining of my arguments and it's work

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mathias.R and Christian.K i have been able to find a solution.

Here's my code:

```
 Process process = new Process
 {
     StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
     {
         FileName = "cmd.exe",
         Arguments = "/c cm whoami",
         UseShellExecute = false,
         RedirectStandardOutput = true,
         CreateNoWindow = true
     }
 };
 process.Start();
 string outpout = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 process.WaitForExit();
```