# Display the result of a command prompt in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10

I'm making an application where I have to enable and disable the UWF in Windows 10.
But I want to intercept the success or failure, the problem is that when I only displays a letter.

```
string output = string.Empty;
        string error = string.Empty;


        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c uwfmgr.exe volume protect c:");
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

        using (StreamReader streamReader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        using (StreamReader streamReader = process.StandardError)
        {
            error = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + error);
            return;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("OK: " + output);
```

Here comes the message box "OK U"

Thanks

Comment: What output you get when you run same command in cmd.exe ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.
I tried to read the articles but given my lack of experience I can apply what it says, Could you give me a little extra help?
The thing I noticed is that I can enable the UWF only if you use the following code

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k uwfmgr.exe volume protect " + cmbBox_Disk.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 2) + " & exit");
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);


processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k uwfmgr.exe filter enable & exit");
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

but the problem is that in this way if there is an error I can not agree with the user.

Comment: You should delete this answer - you don't want to ask more questions in an answer :-)

Comment: I tried to add it in a comment, but told me that there were too many characters

Comment: I added code to my answer - and edited it several times...see if it does what you want now.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the output of the shell, see this answer:

[Process.start: how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

Unfortunately there is no good way to detect errors using process. 
It would be better to use WMI and UWF's WMI provider:

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-wmi-provider-reference

Make sure you read the docs thoroughly though. For example, in order to protect a volume you need to run Protect(); on an instance which has 'currentSession = false'. This instance needs to be created by yourself.
It has some small caveats here an there.