# How to run compiled binary file on android?

Tags: android, xamarin, process

I found here
[Process.start: how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)
how to start process that communicates throught standard i/o, but I get exception **cannot find the specified file**. Thinking about that, I admit it isn't so surprising result, but somehow I can't think out the correct solution to this problem.

How should I start the process, should I put the file elsewhere or use different FileName? Or is Process.Start wrong use here?

This is my code to start the process

```
stockfishProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
stockfishProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "stockfish-8-arm64-v8a";
stockfishProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
stockfishProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
stockfishProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
stockfishProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
stockfishProcess.Start();
```

And this is how I used the compiled binary file. I added it to project as AndroidNativeLibrary.

[image]

Comment: Is `stockfish-8-arm64-v8a` an Android native library or a native shell executable?

Comment: Try the full path to see if it works.

Comment: @SmallChess Full path was path on PC, like C:/... and it didn't work.

Comment: @SushiHangover It is not written on their download page, is there a way how can I get this info from the file?