# How to run a .exe of a C program from .NET WPF?

Tags: c#, c, wpf

I want to run the "**pocketsphinx_continuous.exe**" program which is **written in C** language from my WPF application. Currently I run this using the command prompt.  pocketsphinx_continuous.exe requires parameters.

The command will be something like this. Open cmd, go to the folder where "pocketsphinx_continuous.exe" exists and run,

```
pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -infile test\data\goforward.raw -hmm model\en-us\en-us -lm model\en-us\en-us.lm.bin -dict model\en-us\cmudict-en-us.dict
```

The program prints a string in command prompt. Instead of this I want to get this string to my WPF application.

Say, for a button click I want to run the above program and get the resulting string to a textbox in the same window. Running the C program should happen in the background.

How should I do this? Do I have to write a service between the C and WPF applications?

Comment: This is a very common scenario, if you search you will find many examples. Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start a process with `Process.Start()` and redirect its console output. It's even possible to do this in the background and hide the console window.

Create a new process like this:

```
var process = new Process 
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo 
    {
        FileName = "pocketsphinx_continuous.exe",
        Arguments = "-infile test\data\goforward.raw -hmm model\en-us\en-us -lm model\en-us\en-us.lm.bin -dict model\en-us\cmudict-en-us.dict",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

Now you can start the process and redirect the console output:

```
process.Start();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) 
{
    string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}
```

`line` will contain a line of your program's output and you can do whatever you want with it.