# Can't Get Command to Execute in Console App

Tags: c#, cmd, console-application

I'm writing a small test application. I'm trying to run the command prompt through a C# console app, but I can't get it to work.

Everything I've researched says I am doing it correctly.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main( string[ ] args )
   {
       Process.Start( "cmd", "echo testing" );
       Console.ReadKey( );
   }
}
```

When it runs, the cmd window appears, but "testing" is never written.

Comment: How do you run the program? Where do you expect "testing" to be written?

Comment: You need to pipe the stdout of the process to the stdout of the c# app.  check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Process.Start( "cmd", "/k echo testing" );
```

See cmd's help by `cmd /?`

> CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON |
>   /V:OFF]
>       [[/S] [/C | /K] string]
>
> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
>
> /K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains