# WMI query too slow

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

I need get Office is Activated or need activation and i use normal query in WMI:

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                        "SELECT * FROM " + wmi + " WHERE Name LIKE \"%Office%\" ");

                    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                    { 
                        queryObj["Name"].ToString() + "', '" + queryObj["LicenseStatus"].ToString();
```

But this query sometimes require 45/50 seconds, now I have to understand how to replace it or speed it up, becasue if i use this command from CMD

```
WMIC /NAMESPACE:\\root\CIMV2 PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE LicenseStatus=1 GET Name
```

It respond in 2 seconds! But i can't integrate CMD in C# only if run external command and from CMD i don't have full query access

This query work:

```
WMIC /NAMESPACE:\\root\CIMV2 PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE "name like '%Office%'" Get Name
```

Now add LicenseStatus=1

```
WMIC /NAMESPACE:\\root\CIMV2 PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE "name like '%Office%'" and LicenseStatus=1 Get Name
```

And query not work, why?

Comment: This blog will be useful http://blogs.msdn.com/wmi/archive/2009/06/27/wmi-improving-your-wmi-application-performance-in-fan-out-scenario.aspx
which helps to understand performance differences

Comment: Really cmd is capturable?

Comment: Without like %% the time not change

Comment: @MarcusJ.Kennedy: well, you can run a "console" program and capture it's output in your application See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output#4291965

Comment: Query updated in question, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the WMIC query you gave, you are only pulling the "Name" property which is whats increasing your performance so that your query only runs for 2 seconds.

So this...

```
WMIC /NAMESPACE:\\root\CIMV2 PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE LicenseStatus=1 GET Name
```

Would translate to this query in your code...

```
SELECT Name FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE LicenseStatus=1
```

Your other example is correct but you just need to move your second quotes over

```
WMIC /NAMESPACE:\\root\CIMV2 PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE "name like '%Office%' and LicenseStatus=1" Get Name
```

Which, in your code, would look like this (I added LicenseStatus to the query as well since you reference that property in your routine)

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                        "SELECT Name, LicenseStatus FROM " + wmi + " WHERE Name LIKE \"%Office%\" and LicenseStatus=1");

                    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                    { 
                        queryObj["Name"].ToString() + "', '" + queryObj["LicenseStatus"].ToString();
```

That should run fairly quick since its only getting the two properties you are using.