# How to get console app output string value?

Tags: c#

I have a cpp console app that returns some random strings. How to get its output string?

Below what I have tried to call that cpp console app, but I don't have any idea to get its output string?

```
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.FileName = "/tmp/mycpp.exe ";
        processInfo.Arguments = _jpg;
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = processInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();


        }
```

and the output string looks like below:

```
[root@demo car-make-model-classifier-yolo3-cpp]# ./mycpp helloworld
------------------------------------------------
value1: helloworld1
value2: helloworld2
------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------
value1: helloworld11
value2: helloworld22
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Use [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netcore-3.1). I'm sure there are a lot of answers on SO, but I admit it's not so easy to find them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process.start: how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

Comment: `Process.ExitCode` if that's what you mean. Processes have no output values, they write to the output stream. If you want that output you need to redirect the output stream

Comment: I tried ReadLine but it returns empty