# How to start a process in the background and read standard output

Tags: c#, multiprocessing

I am new to C#, I have to start a very time consuming process from my C# program of course without bearing the loss of ui freeze, also I want to read the output printed by the program in cmd and at last I want a stop button so that I can close the program whenever I want...

Please help..

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output. Also to kill the process you can use Process.Kill()

Comment: But they all are on main ui thread. I have to run a very time consuming process, it will freeze the ui...

Comment: The Process itself gets a new thread, but reading from the Output blocks the main thread. To make it async you could start a new Thread which reads from the process Stdout or use the StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync or StreamReader.ReadLineAsync methods.

Comment: I am a noob can you share some relevant links.

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this question on this site. Did you try to perform a minimal search?

Comment: Yes after searches only I have came here. Plz help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process.start: how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

void startProcess()
{
Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "FileName";
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();

            var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}

MethodInvoker starter = new MethodInvoker(startProcess);

starter.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

for ending the process:

```
p.close()
```

Comment: This is on main ui thread, it will freeze the ui...

Comment: I don't know much I am noob

Comment: Okk I will try. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
void StartProcess(){
   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "yourfile.exe";
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   p.Start();
   var readingThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
      while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream){
         Console.WriteLine(p.StandartOutput.ReadLine());
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
      }
   }
   readingThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why are you doing the system.threading.sleep?

Comment: If you don't use it, the program uses extremly much of your CPU resources (up to 50%). By adding a one millisecond sleep it doesn't take anywhere near this much resources.

Comment: OK thnks I will give it a try