# Can .Net Core CLI be run from within C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, command-line-interface

I am building my first WPF application - a developer tool. I am building it in .Net Core 3.1. I have a requirement to use the .Net Core CLI to create another application from within the tool. I have really two questions:

1. Is this possible? I have done a lot of research but I have found nothing so far.
2. Is there a CLI command to add a new class to a class library project? The tool needs to create a new solution that compiles with all classes it creates added to the project.

Comment: Yes - I know this and that is not my question. I need to run that command and all subsequent command from specific folders from within a running C# WPF application.

Comment: That is a statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. Is this possible? I have done a lot of research but I have found nothing so far.

Of course, it is not even WPF related. You can run the `dotnet` CLI just like any other program with `Process`. The code below will call the help for `dotnet`.

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
   FileName = "dotnet.exe",
   Arguments = "-h"
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

If you do not want do display the console widow, you can add these options to the start info.

```
CreateNoWindow = true,
WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
```

Keep in mind that commands may fail and you should handle the console output to react on that. Look here for a related post that demonstrates how you can [redirect console output.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

> 2. Is there a CLI command to add a new class to a class library project? The tool needs to create a new solution that compiles with all classes it creates added to the project.

Let's do a quick walkthrough to show the essential parts of your application. Since it is is always the same code for calling `dotnet` but with different arguments, I will only show those.

1. Create an new solution with a class library

```
Arguments = @"new classlib -o C:\The\Path\To\Your\Solution -n MyProject"
```

The `classlib` command will create a class library in the given directory with the name `MyProject`.

2. Adding a new class

```
File.Create(@"C:\The\Path\To\Your\Solution\MyClass.cs");
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\The\Path\To\Your\Solution\MyOtherClass.cs", cSharpClassBoilerPlateCode);
```

As far as I know there is no built-in command to create single class files. However, you can just create a `.cs` file with [`File.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netcore-3.1) or [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netcore-3.1) that contains some boilerplate code directly in your project directory. The .NET SDK-style project format includes all source files in the project directory by default, unless you overrode this behavior.

3. Compile the project

```
Arguments = @"build C:\The\Path\To\Your\Solution\MyProject.csproj"
```

---

This is only a starter example. The `dotnet` command line interface offers a lot more options to customize and work with solutions and projects, see below for reference.

- [`dotnet` CLI Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/)
- [`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)
- [`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build)

Comment: Thank You thatguy - exactly what I was looking for. Already tested adding the class to the class lib and works great.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Sure. You can invoke any executable, including the `dotnet` command-line tool, using the `Process.Start` API:

```
//dotnet new wpf:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet", "new wpf");
```

> Is there a CLI command to add a new class to a class library project?

No, but you any file with a matching file extension that you add to the project folder will be considered when building the project so you don't really need to explicitly add a class to the project.