# Execute Raw Mongodb Command/Query with c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am building a .NET application which works as IDE for MongoDB. Here user can enter raw MongoDB query/command.

For example:

```
db.getCollection('Employee').find({
     "_id" : ObjectId("5f70db8e04f2f92d00123456")
})
```

Note: Above code is just for example. The commands vary depending on user's input.

This works fine in Mongo shell.

I tried using MongoDB Driver but it does not support raw MongoDB commands.

Is there a way to achieve using C#?

Also are there any third party libraries which executes raw mongodb commands?

Comment: Did you look at [mongodb blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-c-and-mongodb--read-operations)? is this what you are looking for?

Comment: you can use the original mongo cli  , here is how to run external command  from c# : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Comment: @kiko075. I tried using external command from the provided link. But still facing issues. Once I start the process and connect to mongo I don't get the output back.

As a result I cannot query the MongoDB.

I tried searching different ways to solve this but no luck. Since mongo is widely used I hope there could be a possibility to connect to mongoshell and execute raw mongo queries.

Comment: Basically I want to build a Mongo GUI application similar to Robo 3T.
I want to implement the same way they provide mongo shell UI where user can enter any mongo command and execute.

Comment: another info how to get output messages(bear in mind in mongo cli you can suppress  with --quiet some  messages ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output