# Why i can't launch Robocopy with Process.Start

Tags: c#, robocopy, process.start

I want to run a Robocopy command from my code but it dosn't want to run.

Here's my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.EXE");
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C ROBOCOPY {0} {1} /E /MT:32", srcPath, dstPath);
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I tried this :

`Process.Start("CMD.EXE", string.Format("/C ROBOCOPY {0} {1} /E /MT:32", srcPath, dstPath));`

But it also dosn't work.

I don't know why it only run the cmd with no arguments but when i copy/paste my command on the cmd it work.

I have seen other topic talk about this but i none of them i found a fine answer.

Comment: The application is `robocopy.exe` not `cmd`. Instead of launching robocopy, you're launching a console and tell it to launch `robocopy` with injected arguments. It's VERY easy to create an invalid argument string this way. Use `robocopy.exe` as the executable and pass only the `robocopy` arguments to the `Arguments` property. Also make sure you quote the file names, in case they contain spaces

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Did you try to run the same command manually?

Comment: Yes when i run the command manually it's working

Comment: Define "doesn't work", does it throw an error? Do the files just not copy? What happens? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

The application is `robocopy.exe` not `cmd`. Instead of launching robocopy, you're launching a console and tell it to launch `robocopy` with injected arguments. It's VERY easy to create an invalid argument string this way, especially if the file names contain spaces.

Use `robocopy.exe` as the executable and pass only the `robocopy` arguments to the `Arguments` property. You have to ensure the path arguments are quoted, to take care of paths with spaces, eg :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("robocopy");
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" /E /MT:32", srcPath, dstPath);
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

or

```
Process.Start("robocopy", string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" /E /MT:32", srcPath, dstPath));
```

This will work if `robocopy` is in the user's PATH. If not, you'll have to pass the full path to the executable

Comment: it's not working even with "C:/windows/system32/Robocopy.exe" instead of "robocopy"

Comment: @JoevinFerret first, paths on Windows use a backslash. Second, what does `not working` mean? Do you get an exception? `Start` will throw an exception if the executable can't be found. You can wait for `robocopy` to finish with `Process.WaitForExit()` and read the output from the [Process.StandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-5.0) property. Errors are written to [StandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=net-5.0)

Comment: If the app throws an error, it will write it to the standard error stream

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

- **SOLUTION 0** (EDIT)

You should use double quotes for you paths:

```
string.Format("/C ROBOCOPY \"{0}\" \"{1}\" /E /MT:32", srcPath, dstPath)
```

- **SOLUTION 1**

So I will guess that the problem is `srcPath` and `dstPath`. You must use the **absolute** path!

For example:

```
srcPath = @"C:\source";
dstPath = @"C:\destiny";
```

- **SOLUTION 2**

If this is not your problem, check if you have `write` and/or `read` permissions on the source and destiny paths.

- **SOLUTION 3**

Check this library: [RoboSharp on Github](https://github.com/tjscience/RoboSharp). It is also available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RoboSharp).

- **SOLUTION 4**

Since you are copying from NETWORK, and the code works in the `cmd`, maybe the problem is the **slashes**.

This: `srcPath = "\\127.0.0.1\\";`

is different of: `srcPath = @"\\127.0.0.1\\";`.

[See this link](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2017/06/understand-the-at-symbol-in-c/) to learn more about the **at sign, @**.

Comment: Do you think it's because my source path is on a server ? I think it shouldn't be a problem because it's working when i launch it from the cmd

Comment: First, check the edit. Maybe the problem is the missing ``"quotes"``. About your question, it is hard to say... But if you can copy the files with the ``Windows File Explorer``, you should be able to copy with ``robocopy``.

Comment: Have you tried to run your ``exe`` as ``Administrator``?

Comment: Yes i know and it's work in cmd it's only in my code that it's don't want to work.

Comment: Try read the output from the ``Process``, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291965/5734097) to learn how to. Maybe you get an error explaining what is going on.

Comment: Also, if you are copying from the network, mind the slashes: ``"\\NAME_or_IP\\"`` is cmd is equals to ``@"\\NAME_or_IP\\"`` (in C#) but different from ``"\\NAME_or_IP\\"`` (note the ``@``)