# C# sqlite how to print affected rows from executed sqlite command line .read

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a file named query.sql containing a TRANSACTION, and I want to execute that file using sqlite command line from my C# code. Its works fine, but I cannot get the affected rows from the command line output. I want to get the affected rows and show it using a MessageBox.

My C# code using Process :

```cs
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("sqlite3.exe");
startinfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \".read '{1}'\"",DatabasePath, Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "query.sql"));
//startinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Process.Start(startinfo);
```

view from commandline :

```cs
sqlite3.exe "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\app\database.db" ".read 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\query.sql'"
```

[image: example of my sql file:]

I executed the command and the db got changed, but I cannot capture the affected rows. How to capture the affected rows from that Process?

Comment: Why use from command line instead of the [Sqlite .NET library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite)?

Comment: Yeah, this would be a very good use case for SQLite.NET.

Comment: INSERT commands don't return rows.

Comment: @Magnetron I tried using the library for import case but the performance so different. with library i need to read the sql file with stream reader to assign it to a string and if the file is very huge, it takes very long time to process and use big memory when i see in the diagnostic tools. but i have little doubt if i doing that in wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add `Select Changes();` to the end of your SQL.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes

Then you need to setup your process to redirect the output to your app.

```
startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
var proc = Process.Start(startinfo);
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291965/7182460

While the above should work there is an easier way.
I'm not sure what your reason is for using the command line. You might want to take a look at using an ORM.

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Comment: I tried using the library for import case but the performance so different. with library i need to read the sql file with stream reader to assign it to a string and if the file is very huge, it takes very long time to process and use big memory when i see in the diagnostic tools. but i have little doubt if i doing that in wrong way.

Comment: thanks your code works fine. but i changed the `SELECT changes();` because it always return `1`, i changed to `SELECT total_changes();` and append to end of my sql file. and i will take a look to the link you provide.