# Execute all unit test using a function C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console-application, xunit

Is there a way to execute all of the C# unit tests (`xUnit`) within the console application? So that the end user can see the results while running the program?
Let's say that we have simple `switch case` menu like:

1. Do something,
2. Do something different
3. Run unit tests.

So that when the input from user's keyboard equals 3 all of the unit tests from the project are executed and the result is printed?

Thanks in an advance for the help

Comment: Simply automate the testrunner for xunit? If this is a net core project you can call "dotnet test" with parameters/filters to do what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to run the dotnet test command from the code level? All I want to do is basically to trigger all of the tests once user's input is 3 and print the results to the console for him

Comment: It's a net core project with it's related test project - dotnet test works when I type it into the terminal but I'd have to use it in code so that end user can see the results

Comment: Start the Test process via a `Process.Start` call for the test runner. For the result you may redirect the console output. Presumably its better to let dotnet test create a result file in a format of your choice and show that to the user.

Comment: Sorry, but to make that clear - how to start the Test Process via Process.Start? I'm quite not sure how to call for the test runner

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your tests live in a C# project called `MyTest.csproj`, you'd start them from the CLI via `dotnet test MyTest.csproj`.
If you want to do this from within your own application, you could use `Process.Start` like this:

```cs
if (chosenMenuItem == 3)
  Process.Start("dotnet", "test MyTest.csproj");
```

That will start the test run.

If you want to get the test output as well, you could follow this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291965/4919526