# How to capture real-time output from a native process in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, process, output, real-time

I am attempting to capture real-time output from a native process and forward it to a SignalR client using C#. However, I am not able to capture the output as expected.

I have created a NativeProcess class to handle the process execution and output capture. The relevant part of the code is the StartListeningToOutputAsync method which is supposed to read the output from the process:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using RemoteMaster.Shared.Models;
using Windows.Win32.Foundation;
using Windows.Win32.Security;
using Windows.Win32.System.RemoteDesktop;
using Windows.Win32.System.Threading;
using static Windows.Win32.PInvoke;

namespace RemoteMaster.Shared.Services;

public class NativeProcess : IDisposable
{
    public uint ProcessId { get; private set; }

    public uint ThreadId { get; private set; }

    public SafeFileHandle ProcessHandle { get; private set; }

    public SafeFileHandle ThreadHandle { get; private set; }

    public SafeFileHandle StdOutputReadHandle { get; private set; }


    public event Action<string> OutputReceived;

    public ProcessStartOptions StartOptions { get; set; }

    public NativeProcess(ProcessStartOptions options)
    {
        StartOptions = options;
    }

    public NativeProcess(PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo, SafeFileHandle stdOutputReadHandle)
    {
        ProcessId = procInfo.dwProcessId;
        ThreadId = procInfo.dwThreadId;
        ProcessHandle = new SafeFileHandle(procInfo.hProcess, true);
        ThreadHandle = new SafeFileHandle(procInfo.hThread, true);
        StdOutputReadHandle = stdOutputReadHandle;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var proc = StartInternal(StartOptions) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to start the native process.");
        
        ProcessId = proc.ProcessId;
        ThreadId = proc.ThreadId;
        ProcessHandle = proc.ProcessHandle;
        ThreadHandle = proc.ThreadHandle;
        StdOutputReadHandle = proc.StdOutputReadHandle;
    }

    public static NativeProcess Start(ProcessStartOptions options)
    {
        var process = new NativeProcess(options);
        process.Start();

        return process;
    }

    public async Task StartListeningToOutputAsync()
    {
        if (StdOutputReadHandle == null || StdOutputReadHandle.IsInvalid)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid standard output handle.");
        }

        using var fs = new FileStream(StdOutputReadHandle, FileAccess.Read, 4096, false);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Unicode);
        string line;

        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            OutputReceived?.Invoke(line);
        }
    }

    private static NativeProcess StartInternal(ProcessStartOptions options)
    {
        var procInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        var sessionId = GetSessionId(options.ForceConsoleSession, options.TargetSessionId);
        SafeFileHandle hUserTokenDup = null;
        SafeFileHandle stdOutputReadHandle = null;
        SafeFileHandle stdOutputReadHandleTemp = null;

        try
        {
            if (options.UseCurrentUserToken && TryGetUserToken(sessionId, out hUserTokenDup))
            {
                if (TryCreateInteractiveProcess(hUserTokenDup, options.ApplicationName, options.DesktopName, options.HiddenWindow, out procInfo, out stdOutputReadHandleTemp))
                {
                    stdOutputReadHandle = stdOutputReadHandleTemp;
                    stdOutputReadHandleTemp = null;
                    return new NativeProcess(procInfo, stdOutputReadHandle);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var winlogonPid = GetWinlogonPidForSession(sessionId);
                using var hProcess = OpenProcess_SafeHandle(PROCESS_ACCESS_RIGHTS.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, winlogonPid);
                if (IsProcessOpen(hProcess) && TryGetProcessToken(hProcess, out var hPToken))
                {
                    using (hPToken)
                    {
                        if (TryDuplicateToken(hPToken, out hUserTokenDup))
                        {
                            if (TryCreateInteractiveProcess(hUserTokenDup, options.ApplicationName, options.DesktopName, options.HiddenWindow, out procInfo, out stdOutputReadHandleTemp))
                            {
                                stdOutputReadHandle = stdOutputReadHandleTemp;
                                stdOutputReadHandleTemp = null;
                                return new NativeProcess(procInfo, stdOutputReadHandle);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            hUserTokenDup?.Dispose();
            stdOutputReadHandleTemp?.Dispose();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static bool IsProcessOpen(SafeHandle hProcess) => !hProcess.IsInvalid && !hProcess.IsClosed;

    private static bool TryGetProcessToken(SafeHandle hProcess, out SafeFileHandle hPToken) => OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ACCESS_MASK.TOKEN_DUPLICATE, out hPToken);

    private static bool TryDuplicateToken(SafeHandle hPToken, out SafeFileHandle hUserTokenDup) => DuplicateTokenEx(hPToken, TOKEN_ACCESS_MASK.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, null, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out hUserTokenDup);

    private static uint GetSessionId(bool forceConsoleSession, int? targetSessionId)
    {
        return !forceConsoleSession
            ? FindTargetSessionId(targetSessionId.Value)
            : WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    }

    private static uint GetWinlogonPidForSession(uint sessionId)
    {
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("winlogon"))
        {
            if ((uint)process.SessionId == sessionId)
            {
                return (uint)process.Id;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("No winlogon process found for the given session id.");
    }

    private static uint FindTargetSessionId(int targetSessionId)
    {
        var activeSessions = GetActiveSessions();
        uint lastSessionId = 0;
        var targetSessionFound = false;

        foreach (var session in activeSessions)
        {
            lastSessionId = session.SessionId;
            
            if (session.SessionId == targetSessionId)
            {
                targetSessionFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return targetSessionFound
            ? (uint)targetSessionId
            : lastSessionId;
    }

    private static unsafe bool TryCreateInteractiveProcess(SafeHandle hUserTokenDup, string applicationName, string desktopName, bool hiddenWindow, out PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo, out SafeFileHandle stdOutputReadHandle)
    {
        if (!CreatePipe(out stdOutputReadHandle, out SafeFileHandle stdOutputWriteHandle, null, 0))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create pipe for standard output.");
        }

        fixed (char* pDesktopName = $@"winsta0\{desktopName}")
        {
            var startupInfo = new STARTUPINFOW
            {
                cb = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<STARTUPINFOW>(),
                lpDesktop = pDesktopName,
                hStdOutput = (HANDLE)stdOutputWriteHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
                hStdError = (HANDLE)stdOutputWriteHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
                dwFlags = STARTUPINFOW_FLAGS.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
            };

            var dwCreationFlags = SetCreationFlags(hiddenWindow);
            applicationName += char.MinValue;
            
            var appName = new Span<char>(applicationName.ToCharArray());
            var result = CreateProcessAsUser(hUserTokenDup, null, ref appName, null, null, false, dwCreationFlags, null, null, startupInfo, out procInfo);
            
            stdOutputWriteHandle.Close();
            
            return result;
        }
    }

    private static PROCESS_CREATION_FLAGS SetCreationFlags(bool hiddenWindow)
    {
        var dwCreationFlags = PROCESS_CREATION_FLAGS.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | PROCESS_CREATION_FLAGS.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
        
        dwCreationFlags |= hiddenWindow
            ? PROCESS_CREATION_FLAGS.CREATE_NO_WINDOW
            : PROCESS_CREATION_FLAGS.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
        
        return dwCreationFlags;
    }

    private static bool TryGetUserToken(uint sessionId, out SafeFileHandle hUserToken)
    {
        var userTokenHandle = default(HANDLE);
        var success = WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, ref userTokenHandle);
        hUserToken = new SafeFileHandle(userTokenHandle, true);
        
        return success;
    }

    public static unsafe List<WTS_SESSION_INFOW> GetActiveSessions()
    {
        var sessions = new List<WTS_SESSION_INFOW>();
        
        if (WTSEnumerateSessions(HANDLE.Null, 0, 1, out var sessionInfo, out var count))
        {
            var dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf<WTS_SESSION_INFOW>();
            var current = sessionInfo;
            
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var session = Marshal.PtrToStructure<WTS_SESSION_INFOW>((IntPtr)current);
                current += dataSize;
                
                if (session.State == WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive)
                {
                    sessions.Add(session);
                }
            }
        }

        return sessions;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ProcessHandle?.Dispose();
        ThreadHandle?.Dispose();
        StdOutputReadHandle?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace RemoteMaster.Shared.Models;

public class ProcessStartOptions
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    public int TargetSessionId { get; set; }

    public bool ForceConsoleSession { get; set; }

    public string DesktopName { get; set; }

    public bool HiddenWindow { get; set; }

    public bool UseCurrentUserToken { get; set; }

    public ProcessStartOptions(string applicationName, int targetSessionId)
    {
        ApplicationName = applicationName;
        TargetSessionId = targetSessionId;
    }
}
```

I need to receive real-time output from a process running with it so that it can be sent to a connected SignalR client, for example.

But it's not working. I even created a minimal project to test it:

```cs
using RemoteMaster.Shared.Models;
using RemoteMaster.Shared.Services;

var scriptPath = CreateAndSaveCmdScript();

var options = new ProcessStartOptions($"cmd.exe /k \"{scriptPath}\"", -1)
{
    ForceConsoleSession = true,
    DesktopName = "default",
    HiddenWindow = true,
    UseCurrentUserToken = true
};

try
{
    using var process = NativeProcess.Start(options);
    process.OutputReceived += Console.WriteLine;
    await process.StartListeningToOutputAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}

string CreateAndSaveCmdScript()
{
    var scriptContent = @"
        echo Hello from the script!
        timeout /t 2 /nobreak
        echo Script is still running...
        timeout /t 2 /nobreak
        echo Script finished!
    ";

    var tempScriptPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "tempScript.cmd");
    File.WriteAllText(tempScriptPath, scriptContent);

    return tempScriptPath;
}
```

Attempts:
I have created a minimal project to test the output capture but all I get is the following output indicating that the process exited with code 0:

(process 15988) exited with code 0.
...

Expected vs Actual Results:
I expect to see the real-time output from the process, but I am only getting a message indicating that the process has exited.

How do you read the output then?

Comment: Why are you not using the built in [Process class to get output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)?

Comment: @JonasH If only it were that simple. I need to start a process in a user's session from a Windows service, so I wrote a class like this

Comment: You should create *different* pipes for stdin, stdout, and stderr, and then close stdin. Don't close stdout; the child process will do that when it exits. You'll also need to pass inheritable handles (probably duplicating your pipe handles).