# Start CMD by using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, cmd, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I am trying to start the CMD application in windows by using the following code, but it doesn't work as expected. Several examples from different websites shows that "cmd" as an argument in the ProcessBuilder construct should work.

What do I have to do to make my Java app open the CMD application in windows?

```
 public class JavaTest
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");

         try 
         {
             pb.start();
             System.out.println("cmd started");
         } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }  
     }
 }
```

When I try to use a non-existing application it actually prints out an error, so that means it actually runs "CMD". But the CMD application doesn't pop up as expected?

Comment: If you called your auto mechanic and said "my car doesn't work", what would his first question be?  If you don't tell us what the error message was, how do you expect to get any help?

Comment: Before jumping up with a fancy comment,try reading what the OP says. _so that means it actually runs "CMD". But the CMD application doesn't pop up as expected?_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [start](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) command. Actually, even I don't see a new command prompt popping up, but you can check that a new `cmd.exe` is definitely started using your `task manager`.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "start");
```

Though, the same functionality can be achieved using `Runtime.exec()`, and this actually pops up a new command prompt.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start");
```

Comment: The ProcessBuilder doesn't work as expected (Which I find very, very weird) - But the "exec()" method does the job. Thank you!

Comment: String[] cmd = new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "start"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process process = pb.start();

Comment: I don't know what /C mean?,it's not the path of C drive

Comment: @john please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/what-does-cmd-c-mean

Answer (score 15):

To use it with ProcessBuilder you must separate the commands like this:

```
final List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();                

commands.add("cmd.exe");
commands.add("/C");
commands.add("start");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

**use this command if you are windows**

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "ping -n 3 google.com");
```