# How to invoke cmd commands in from a Java program in Windows?

Tags: java, cmd

I want to create an application which can compile and run external programs. For this I need to run compiler commands from the command prompt (commands like javac and gcc).
I tried the approach given here - [Run cmd commands through java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java)

This is my code

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ProcessBuilder builder=new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe","javac F://Test.java","java -cp F:// Test");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.start();
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

But when I run it, it just executes the 1st command (cmd.exe), displays this output :

*Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.*

And then it waits indefinitely. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT-
My question was identified as the duplicate of this question - [Start CMD by using ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954194/start-cmd-by-using-processbuilder) . But I believe that question asks for how to start cmd from java code. I need my program to execute cmd commands as well. E.g. I want to execute javac command on after starting a process for cmd.

Comment: `cmd /c ...` to execute other apps...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start CMD by using ProcessBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954194/start-cmd-by-using-processbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gcc ...");
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)

You should also read this post:

[Want to invoke a linux shell command from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java)

Most of it isn't Linux specific. It contains useful info about how to handle standard-error or stream redirection (which is also possible in windows shell).