# java process builder start cmd with some other directory

Tags: java, processbuilder

Using process builder opening the CMD and execute a particular file in D drive.

Below is my initial code

this is CMD opening with my current working directory (IDE project location initially :C:\Users\xxx\yyy\testjson>)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "start");
        Process p = pb.start();
```

I want to add the below cmd command in my code, and execute a particular file in that folder, let me know how can?

```
1.change the directory to D
2.move to the particular folder into that D drive
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954194/start-cmd-by-using-processbuilder

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is `ProcessBuilder::directory(String)` which sets the working directory for the new process; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)).

```
   Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "start")
                .directory(new File("D:/some/directory"))
                .start();
```