# Java ProcessBuilder to start execute multiple commands sequentially in Linux

Tags: java, processbuilder

I would like to execute 2 or more commands sequentially through my Java Application using ProcessBuilder class. I Have tried multiple options as suggested in other responses/forums but no luck.

Here are the things I have tried:

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ls", ";", "pwd");
```

Gives me following error :

Errors : ls: ;: No such file or directory
Errors : ls: pwd: No such file or directory

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "&&", "pwd");
```

Gives me similar error:

Errors : ls: &&: No such file or directory
Errors : ls: pwd: No such file or directory

```
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("ls");
    command.add(";");
    command.add("pwd");
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

Gives me following error:

Errors : ls: ;: No such file or directory
Errors : ls: pwd: No such file or directory

My OS is Linux/Mac-OSX.

Answer (score 31):

Your approaches are equivalent to calling `ls` with the specified arguments. In Bash notation, what you're running is:

```
ls ';' pwd
ls '&&' pwd
```

If you want `ls` and `pwd` to be run as separate commands, you can use Bash (or another shell language) to wrap them into a single command:

```
bash -c 'ls ; pwd'
```

which you can call this way:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "ls ; pwd");
```

Comment: @ruakh Can you please tell me how I can do this wrapping with windows based PsExec.exe. As a example navigate to "C" drive and create a directory called "abc" ex: new ProcessBuilder("psexec", "-c", "cd c:\ ; mkdir abc");. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Channa: I don't know about the general case, but I think your specific example could be written as `new ProcessBuilder("psexec", computer, "mkdir", "C:\\abc")`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using ProcessBuilder to compile java program like this and it works for me:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","cd " + dir,
            " & javac " + mapClassName + ".java -cp " + pathToProjectClasses);
```

- cmd.exe : it's start the command prompt.
- \c : not sure what its doing but its important, you can see this link for more information [(\? cmd commands)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/what-does-cmd-c-mean)
- cd + dir : is the first command and its change the directory to a certain path which is dir.
- & : its mean start the second command after you finish the first one
- javac : this word and the rest of the string is the second command
- -cp : path to external class used by the class you want to compile.

So I have 2 commands, first one is `cd` command and second one is `javac` command and i execute them sequentially using `&`.

Sorry for my bad writing skills, if I haven't explained my code well please ask me about anything you want to know.

Comment: /c is for auto close

Answer (score 4):

You could get the Process from [ProcessBuilder.start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29) from the first command, wait using [waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) and then launch the second one.

Comment: Can you share an example