# My code not executing command code its only shows the command prompt but it doesn't execute the command

Tags: c#

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Process proc = new Process();
     ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
     psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
     psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
     psi.Arguments = "netsh wlan start hostednetwork";
     proc.StartInfo = psi;
     proc.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make cmd execute the command, you have to use the `/C` option.

```
psi.Arguments = "/C netsh wlan start hostednetwork";
```

But you shouldn't really need to involve cmd.exe at all. `netsh` is an executable in itself, so you can invoke it directly.

```
psi.FileName = "netsh.exe";
psi.Arguments = "wlan start hostednetwork";
```

Comment: If anyone wondering; [What does cmd `/C` mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/what-does-cmd-c-mean)