# Change from child process exec to spawn dont work

Tags: node.js, child-process

I use the child process **exec** and I need to switch to child process spawn

This is working for me.

```
var child = child_process.exec("npm install express --save" options, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    .....
 });
```

when I do the switch to spawn it doesnt work I got error

```
var child = child_process.spawn("npm install express --save" options);


Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
```

I try even with 
`var child = child_process.spawn("npm", ["install express --save"], options)`;

and it doesnt work for me, what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are on Windows environment.

So, you have to enter terminal and then use commands what you want.

We see in Node.js docs [child_process.exec()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) method already has this spec in its options by default according to operating system.

> shell String Shell to execute the command with (Default: '/bin/sh' on
>   UNIX, 'cmd.exe' on Windows, The shell should understand the -c switch
>   on UNIX or /s /c on Windows. On Windows, command line parsing should
>   be compatible with cmd.exe.)

So when using spawn, things are changing.

```
var child = child_process.spawn("cmd",["/c","npm install express --save"], options);
```

The above code block, starts new instance of Windows command interpreter`(cmd)` and carries out command specified by string and then terminates`(/c)` , finally our specific command `npm install express --save` works on Windows command interpreter.[windows cmd commands references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/what-does-cmd-c-mean)