# Running a Windows executable as a foreground process

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, service, cmd

I want to run an executable as a foreground process. By this I mean I go to the shell (lets assume `cmd`) and can launch the executable and remain attached to the `console/stdout` of that application.

For example:

```
C:\APPS MyApp.exe
```

Normally `cmd` will exit after this command. But I want to remain attached to it till the application exits. Not sure if this is possible in Windows.

**Note:**

I come from a Linux background, so some of the terminology might not be relevant here.

Comment: may be you look for `/K` switch `cmd /K MyApp.exe` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/515380/6401656

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're asking, but my best guess is that you need to build the executable as a console application.  Or perhaps you just need `start /wait MyApp.exe`.

Comment: Is this actually `C:\APPS.bat MyApp.exe`? If so, does it do `START "" %1`?

Comment: If MyApp.exe isn't a console application, then it doesn't automatically inherit the console handle from its parent process (every Windows process has a `ConsoleHandle` for attaching to one and only one console). Even if it inherits console buffer handles in its `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError`, they'll be closed at startup (by the kernel32 init routine) since the process doesn't have a valid console handle.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I respect you opinion but this a use case of Mesos/Marathon application for Windows. Which is or will be a software tool used by most of the developers and hence it makes sense to ask question here. Also, Windows application are managed in a programmatic way so a help/opinion of developer is much more important here.

Comment: @QasimSarfraz, have you resolved the problem? If so, you can add your own answer. If not, please update the question to clarify it based on the comments.

Comment: Hey, @eryksun I haven't been able to resolve the issue but let me update the question in accordingly with comments.