# How to kill all browser windows and drivers before test execution on Windows

Tags: c#, selenium

**Resources : C# , Selenium 3.5 , NUnit , Windows , VS17**

I want to kill all previous browser (let's take chrome.exe for now) windows as well as chromedriver.exe before I kick off test execution.

I know this command

> Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F

or

> Taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /F

but I  am not sure how to use/implement in Selenium - C#.

The code below does not seem to be working if I run before init:

```
//we can give any process name to handle this
Process[] chromeDriverProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver");
foreach (var chromeDriverProcess in chromeDriverProcesses)
{
    // that's how we can kill all chromedriver 
    chromeDriverProcess.Kill();
}
```

The reason I want to do this clean-up is because I want to run this with Jenkins and other VMs and we are seeing some issues. Issue can be resolved if we kill/ clear browser/driver before execution.

Please let me know if we have better solution to do this.

I am using this until I get a good solution:

```
if (Settings.BrowserType.Equals(Constant.Chrome))
{
    // check chrome driver  browser and kill
    Process[] chromeAndDriverProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver");
    foreach (var chromeDriverProcess in chromeAndDriverProcesses)
    {
        chromeDriverProcess.Kill();
    }
    // check chrome browser and kill 
    chromeAndDriverProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
    foreach (var chromeDriverProcess in chromeAndDriverProcesses)
    {
        //chromeDriverProcess.Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be working as far as I tried

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo p;
p = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C "+ "taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = p;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
proc.Close();
```

Refer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fe9e588-5237-4095-a618-75cc00e25263/executing-dos-commands-thru-c-code?forum=csharpgeneral) for more details

Comment: It looks ok on local but what is "/C" is here ? how will this behave on random machine ? thanks for your comment

Comment: /C specifies cmd.exe to execute the command and exit.. Refer this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/515316/1206062

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach(Process P in Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver"))
    P.Kill();
foreach(Process P in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
    P.Kill();
```

Can you clarify what you mean by

> this below seems not working if I run before init :

Comment: You can read broken english better than I can.  Nowhere in that post does it say he tried that.  It's in the comments from what looks like a copy-pasted example, which does not guarantee it was uncommented and attempted.

Comment: It's right there in the code he put in the post.  Yours is just written differently than what is posted.  Just saying, not trying to start a war here.

Comment: @Wolf, thanks for your comment. But I already tried your solution. Sorry for my broken question.

Answer (score 0):

The question `I want to kill all previous browser` shouldn't arise at all when following the **Best Practices** with **`Selenium`**.

While automating through **`Selenium`** as per the best practices you should invoke the **`quit()`** method within the `tearDown() {}`. Invoking **`quit()`** `DELETE`s the current browsing session through sending **"quit"** command with **{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}** and finally sends the **GET** request on **/shutdown** `EndPoint`. Here is an example below :

```
1503397488598   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> DELETE /session/8e457516-3335-4d3b-9140-53fb52aa8b74 
1503397488607   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   -> 37:[0,4,"quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
1503397488821   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /shutdown
```

So on invoking **`quit()`** method the `Web Browser` session and the `WebDriver` instance gets killed completely. hence you don't have to incorporate additional **Taskkill** commands which looks to be an overhead.

---

### Answer to this question :

Still if you want to execute **Taskkill** shell command to kill the `Chrome Web Browser` session and the `ChromeDriver` you can use the following code blocks :

- Kill the **`Chrome Web Browser`** :

  ```
  string str_shell_command_chrome;
  str_shell_command_chrome = "taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T";
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",str_shell_command_chrome);
  ```
- Kill the **`ChromeDriver`** :

  ```
  string str_shell_command_chromedriver;
  str_shell_command_chromedriver = "taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T";
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",str_shell_command_chromedriver);
  ```

---

### Trivia

To hide the `command prompt` while killing the `ChromeDriver` binary, you can use the following block of code :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was not looking Quit, Close, Dispose methods. My questions is when you are copying  automation on different machine which could have some Chrome.exe/Chromedriver.exe (some possibility) open then how you are going to shot it down ? We don't want to run automation if there any single Chrome.exe/Chromedriver.exe exist. First kill off them and then start execution.

Comment: @MikeASP Actually my Answer does contains a section to your individual query. Now I have made a separate section. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: It's not working. It can open CMD but can not provide 'taskkill' command there. string str_shell_command_chromedriver;
str_shell_command_chromedriver = "taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",str_shell_command_chromedriver);