# How to free and release closed Chrome browsers' memories in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a multi-threading automation that uses a lot of multiple Chrome browsers *(can be repeatedly)* with Selenium and C#.

I tried to use everything including "--incognito", "--disable-application-cache", waiting a second before opening another browser, `driver.Close()`, `.Quit()` and `.Dispose()`. Here's the code sample:

```
IWebDriver[] drivers = new IWebDriver[AUTOMATION_NUM];
int QUEUE_BROWSERS_TO_OPEN = 0;

Thread mainThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < AUTOMATION_NUM && !EXIT; i++)
    {
        ...
        Thread driverThread = new Thread(() => {
            ...
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--incognito", "--disable-application-cache"); // headless or non-headless

            IWebDriver driver = drivers[instance];
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, chromeOptions, TIMEOUT_FROM);
            ...
            ++QUEUE_BROWSERS_TO_OPEN;
            ...
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
        });

        _machineThreads.Add(driverThread);
        driverThread.IsBackground = true;
        driverThread.Start();

        while (i < AUTOMATION_NUM && !EXIT)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            if (QUEUE_BROWSERS_TO_OPEN > 0 && BROWSERS_OPEN < BROWSER_NUM)
                --QUEUE_BROWSERS_TO_OPEN;
        }
    }

    Thread endThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        foreach (Thread machineThread in _machineThreads)
            machineThread.Join();

        ...
    });
    endThread.Start();
});
mainThread.Start();
```

And have suggested my client to kill all "chromedriver.exe" processes by clicking a button to execute this code:

```
Process[] chromeDriverProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver");

foreach (var chromeDriverProcess in chromeDriverProcesses)
    chromeDriverProcess.Kill();
```

But my client is still saying that the closed and finished automated browsers' memories are still there?

[image: Closed Chrome browsers' memories]

Any working solution how can I prevent my client's high-end PC from restarting to free up Chrome memory or from being frozen before using the automation again? Any other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

There is command to kill all open browsers windows(chrome.exe) and chrome driver process associated with that browser window (chromedriver.exe)

**To kill chrome driver process**

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "TASKKILL /f  /IM  CHROMEDRIVER.EXE";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

**To kill chrome browser window**

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "TASKKILL /f  /IM  CHROME.EXE";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

For more information refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984415/how-to-kill-all-browser-windows-and-drivers-before-test-execution-on-windows) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)
hope this helps...

Comment: good point here is the distinction between chromedriver and chrome browser.  strange that closing the driver here didn't seem to close the browser (which is what's listed in the screenshot)  +1