# start command keeps creating extra window

Tags: batch-file

When I run a command such as `start "" "file.bat" CMD /C` assuming that file.bat does not contain the `exit` command within, the start command leaves the window previously containing file.bat open. Is there any way to open a batch file in a separate window, but have it behave as if the user personally opened the file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Exactly what do you want to happen? You want the new window to close after it's done?

Comment: Yes. However, the window does not close unless the exit command was in file.bat, or if the file ran without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call your command slightly differently:

```
start cmd /c "file.bat"
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is the reason: start cmd /c "file.bat" works properly.**
  [What does cmd /C mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/what-does-cmd-c-mean) - Found through this question.

```
cmd /?
    Starts a new instance of the Windows XP command interpreter

 CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON |
 /V:OFF] [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

 /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then
 terminates

 /K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains

 /S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)

 /Q      Turns echo off

 /D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see
 below)

 /A      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be
 ANSI

 /U      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be
         Unicode

 /T:fg   Sets the foreground/background colors (see COLOR /? for more
 info)

 /E:ON   Enable command extensions (see below)

 /E:OFF  Disable command extensions (see below)

 /F:ON   Enable file and directory name completion characters (see
 below)

 /F:OFF  Disable file and directory name completion characters (see
 below)

 /V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
         delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
         variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
         at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
         loop.

 /V:OFF  Disable delayed environment expansion.
```