# Why does my Java code execute the cmd command without responding?

Tags: java, windows, command-line, jmeter, command

I want to use runtime to execute cmdline. This command is to generate `example_jtl.jtl` and `example_visual` (a blank folder and new file in here) by `example.jmx`. The Java code is without error after running, but there is no new file and folder. What should I do?

```java
try {
    System.out.println("begin cmd");
    Runtime mt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    //mt.exec("cmd \\c ionic -v");
    String cmd = "cmd D:\\Programming\\JMeter\\apache-jmeter-5.5\\bin\\jmeter -n -t D:\\Programming\\JMeter\\apache-jmeter-5.5\\result\\example.jmx -l D:\\Programming\\JMeter\\apache-jmeter-5.5\\result\\example_jtl.jtl -e -o D:\\Programming\\JMeter\\apache-jmeter-5.5\\result\\example_visual";
    Process pro = mt.exec(cmd);
    InputStream ers= pro.getErrorStream();
    pro.waitFor();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After the program is executed, the `example_jtl.jtl` file and the `example_visual` folder should be generated under the `/result` folder.

Comment: What is the content of your error stream `ers`?

Comment: Your problem is similar to the follow one, please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5711150/7478145

Comment: Your code does nothing to obtain the process output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change your command from `cmd` to [`cmd /c`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/what-does-cmd-c-mean) because currently you're just kicking off a [CMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) instance and the rest is simply ignored.

Also be aware that it's possible to kick off a JMeter test using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html), take a look at [StandardJMeterEngine](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/StandardJMeterEngine.html) class JavaDoc and [JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-command-line) article for more details if needed

Comment: thanks，I added /c and it work correctly！